# How to get the last table cell value of the first row on a table which loads dynamically?

Tags: jquery

I have a table which is build and loaded dynamically, meaning the table is generated by code on `document ready event`.

I need to get the first row (not the header) and the value of the last cell when the page loads (document ready).

*This is a working example:*

```
<table id="example">
    <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>Points</th>
        <th hidden="hidden">Secret Code</th>
    </tr>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Eve</td>
        <td>Jackson</td>
        <td>94</td>

        <!--Onload get this cell value-->
        <td hidden="hidden">1</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Robert</td>
        <td>Groves</td>
        <td>1000</td>
        <td hidden="hidden">2</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Hamm</td>
        <td>XYZ</td>
        <td hidden="hidden">3</td>
    </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

*JS:*

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function(){

        alert($("#example tbody tr").eq(1).find('td:last').text());
    });

</script>
```

I cannot get this to work on the table that is being dynamically generated.
I simply get an empty value.

Comment: If you provide an example of the dynamic table I will help you. Does it have a ````tbody```` element, for example?

Comment: Just check the DOM Tree Structure and post the dom tree structure after the page is loaded and table is dynamically created.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        console.log($("#example tbody tr:first").find('td:last').html());
    });
</script>
```

Please use "tr:first" - it will find first row. Then find last cell "td:last". And get value from td via "html()", not "text()".

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#example tbody tr:first-child td:last-child" ).html();
```

Comment: It selects the tbody->tr->td since there is no td exists in thead. Optionally we can add tbody inside the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

In the example you provided, all is well, but we're processing hidden elements. We just have to remove them first:

```
$('[hidden]').remove();
```

Working Demo: http://jsbin.com/tebudi/edit?js,output

Comment: Even though it should  show the text of hidden elements in that case.In that case this is not a solution at all

Comment: I wrote this assuming you didn't want the hidden elements. Oops

Comment: And by the way first and last properties are also valid..Check https://api.jquery.com/last-selector/